# How make struts2 see my properties file

Tags: java, jsp, properties, struts2

Hi I have this project structure

[image]

and in my `index.jsp` I have this code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
        <s:text name="index.title" />
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <s:form action="Login">
        <s:textfield key="index.login" name="login" />
        <s:password key="index.password" name="password" />
        <s:submit/>
    </s:form>
  </body>
</html>
```

my `content.property` file looks like this:

```
index.hello = Hello user./n/r Please login
index.login = Login
index.password = Password
index.title = Login Page
```

and when i start the project, struts2 is not getting info from my property file.
please tell me what i made wrong
I can't find anything helpful on the internet
help me please
thanks =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your properties file needs to be in the your `classes` directory under `WEB-INF` or a sub-directory of `classes` directory.

Let's assume that you have this structure 
`.../Web-INF/classes/property/content.properties`,
you will need to do this in your `struts.xml`

`<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="property.content" />`

Comment: do not work. I put my property file into web folder than into web-inf folder but struts don't sea it

Comment: @Aleksei From the image that you posted, seems your properties file name is `content.properties` and it's location is `../src/property/content.properties`. Am i right?

Comment: Yes. but I try to put it in differebt places

Comment: @Aleksei Make sure it is under `classes` directory.

Comment: Ohh i solve my problem.. I didn't write <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="property.content" /> in srtuts.xml and only now see that you tell me to write it thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

First rename your `content.properties` to `global_en.properties`. Later put it in `src` folder

Answer (score 1):

You have done all things OK but you have not kept the property file name as of the Action name . The name should be Login.property.

Also please make sure that the property file must be in the same package as of the Action against it is being created.

Please refer the following link for details:

http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/message-resource-files.html

Thanks,
Shahid Saeed Khan