# Why is jsp not seeing default attribute in property file?

Tags: jsp, properties, struts2, struts-tags

I am doing this beginner [Struts2 login tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-create-struts-2-application-eclipse-example/)
And i got it working, except, when the Login page is accessed it doesn't first find the attributes for the labels. So instead of:
[image] 
I get Login page:
[image]
And error page:
[image]
It does however find the attribute when the login is successful by using a simple property tag `<s:property value="username" />`
[image]

What am i overlooking here?

Login.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Struts 2 - Login Application</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Struts 2 - Login Application</h2>
<s:actionerror />
<s:form action="login.action" method="post">
    <s:textfield name="username" key="label.username" size="20" />
    <s:password name="password" key="label.password" size="20" />
    <s:submit method="authenticate" key="label.login" align="center" />
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Welcome.jsp (when login is successful)

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Howdy, <s:property value="username" />...!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

login.xml included by struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC 
'-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN' 
'http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd'>

<struts>
      <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
        value="Credentials" />
    <package name="Login" namespace="/login" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="login"
    method ="authenticate"
            class="Login.LoginAction">
            <result name="success">/login/Welcome.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/login/Login.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

LoginAction class:

```
package Login;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport{
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String authenticate() {

     if (this.username.equals("admin") 
                && this.password.equals("admin123")) {
            return "success";
        } else {
            addActionError(getText("error.login"));
            return "error";
        }
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Property File Credentials.properties

```
label.username= Username
label.password= Password
label.login= Login
error.login= Invalid Username/Password. Please try again.
```

File structure: 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put all resources for all actions in default struts resource bundel, or dived each action resources in its own packge.

I suggest the first approach which eliminates lots of duplications and you can use **jrc-editor** to easily manage all your resource bundels.

So in your sample after running the server the file must be copied to **WEB-INF/classes/resources/** then

```
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
        value="resources/login/Credentials.properties" />
```

PS: you can have

```
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
        value="resources/login/Credentials.properties,resources/login/Otherfile.properties" />
```

Comment: i cant recall what the solution was, but this sounds like the most probable answer, so i'm accepting it, as i haven't revisited this project for a couple years now.

Answer (score 1):

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213982/how-make-struts2-see-my-properties-file?rq=1), it appears to be a file structure problem. Apparently property files need to go under WEB-INF. The structure i was using was that provided once specifying the framework as Struts2 after following the [NetBeans framework tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/framework-adding-support.html), which had an example project with properties not under WEB-INF.

Comment: actually, i now dont think its a directory problem. because double-checking it the example project is not under WEB-INF but it still works. 
I will upload a pic of my file structure.

the problem seems to be, that its not accessing the attributes until the form is submitted / action is provided. The example project didnt need to do this.

Comment: the example file didnt specify the property name, so i have renamed Credentials.properties to be package.properties and it now correctly accesses on the error page, but still not on the initial page before the action has occured.

Answer (score 0):

> use <s:message>

```
<s:form action="login.action" method="post">
    <s:message code="label.username" text="defUsername">
    <s:textfield name="username" size="20" />

    <s:message code="label.password" text="defPassword">
    <s:password name="password" size="20" />

    <s:submit method="authenticate" align="center" >
      <s:message code="label.login" var="var_lbl_login">
    </s:submit>
</s:form>
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `<s:message>`.